# ForkJoinPool exit without processing all elements in the ParallelStream

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I am executing a parallel stream with n number of elements; however the the forJoin finish before my collection 'records' processes all elements in parallel stream.

Below my code:

```
//Created my own ForkJoinPool in order to avoid the common pool
   final ForkJoinPool forJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(commonPool.getParallelism() * 2);

   final AtomicInteger at = new AtomicInteger();


   forJoinPool.execute(() -> records.parallelStream().forEach(
       e -> logger.info("Finished:{}, id:{} ", myService.convert(e, at.incrementAndGet()),
           at.get())));
```

Am I missing something in Parallel Stream? I was expecting ForJoinPool to be closed after all elements in forEach(... are executed.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be documented clearly, but `ForkJoinPool`, by default, uses daemon threads. In other words, in your code, the program must complete before the task you submitted for execution has time to complete. You'll have to wait/block until the task is complete.

Use `submit` to get a `ForkJoinTask`.

```
ForkJoinTask<?> task = forJoinPool.submit(() -> records.parallelStream().forEach(
   e -> logger.info("Finished:{}, id:{} ", myService.convert(e, at.incrementAndGet()),
       at.get())));
task.get(); // blocks until completion
```

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis, I used your code and even with get, but I have same problem.  I will give you more information about my problem. 
The collection has 2000 records;however, I see in the logs only 1900 ids processed. When I monitor the threads, the thread pool is completed, even though, I have more Ids to process in my collection. Other thing to consider, if my collection has 1000 records or less, I see the application working properly and all records are processed;however, after 1000 elements, I see this behavior happening.

Answer (score 0):

@SotiriosDelimanolis
I found the issue!!! The problem was related to null pointer exception inside my service, so the parallel stream is stopping when one error is happening, so I had to catch and/or avoid NullPointerException in my code in order to make it work. Now I can execute big collections in parallel with no ISSUE!!!

In conclusion if one exception bubble up to the parallel stream :

```
records.parallelStream().forEach(
       e -> logger.info("Finished:{}, id:{} ", myService.convert(e, at.incrementAndGet())
```

It is going to stop the processing of the collection "records".